# q-municate (QuickBlox)

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I'm developing an android based chat application using Quickblox as the back end. So I downloaded their open source android chat application (q-municate). I was able to compile it without any issues and deployed this into my Samsung s dous. everything works fine. But when the app goes background it completely stops all the communications. As a result the other end users see this as user offline. Also when the other end user sent a chat message the current user not get notified. Is this normal behavior of this app (q-municate) ? Or may be I'm missing something here. Any help will be much appriciated

Thanks

Comment: Read their documentation: http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Chat_in_background_mode

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems its login off when the app goes background. But my question is how is the user knows that he got message while the app is in background ? Push notifications ?